# Ffmpeg script cuts out sound

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have this ffmpeg script I'm running to automatically convert videos to instagram's accepted coded

The script looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 20M -probesize 20M -y -re -f lavfi -i "movie=filename='file.mp4':loop=5, setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 3500k -vsync 2 -t 59 -acodec aac -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=1080:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1080:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:white" -crf 24 new_file.mp4
```

However that seems to cut out the audio, and I can't seem to find out how to prevent that? I didn't use any -an or anything, and when messing around the audio keeps being cut out? Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movie filter, by default, only reads one video stream from the input.

For looping, stream_loop is available without having to use filters.

`ffmpeg -analyseduration 20M -probesize 20M -y -re -stream_loop 5 -i "file.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 3500k -vsync cfr -t 59 -acodec aac -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=1080:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1080:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:white" -crf 24 new_file.mp4`